# Apply color gradient to ggraph's `geom_conn_bundle`

Tags: r, ggplot2, gradient, linear-gradients, ggraph

**Context**

I am using `ggraph` to arrange nodes (leaves of a tree) in a circular dendrogram and then add connections between some of the nodes (using hierarchical bundling using `geom_conn_bundle`):

```
library(ggraph)
library(igraph)

# Example data
edges <- data.frame(from="root", to=paste("leaf", seq(1,100), sep=""))
vertices <- data.frame(name = unique(c(as.character(edges$from), as.character(edges$to))) ) 
tree <- graph_from_data_frame( edges, vertices=vertices )

# Drawing nodes
pr <- ggraph(tree, layout = "dendrogram", circular = TRUE) + 
    geom_edge_diagonal(alpha = 0.2)

# Example connection
pr <- pr + geom_conn_bundle(
    data = get_con(from = 23, to = 42),
    alpha=0.8, 
    width=3, 
    colour="skyblue", 
    tension = 0.9
)
print(pr)
```

This nicely displays a nearly transparent dendrogram and some (in this example one) connections in `skyblue`.

**Problem / Desired output**

What I'd like though, is the direction of the connection being indicated by a color gradient (i.e. starting with green, slowly changing into red) instead of showing the connection in just one color (skyblue). How can I achive such a color gradient using R and ggraph's `geom_conn_bundle`?

The following excerpt from [Holten (2006)](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/stamp/stamp.jsp?tp=&arnumber=4015425&tag=1) can serve of an example of how I'd like the connections to look:

[image]

Comment: We'd need a [sample of data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) to be able to really help

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to comment. I added three lines of R code to my question. They generate example data. Not sure if it will help folks to answer because to me the question appears to be more on `ggraph` than on my (or any) particular implementation :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Several of the `ggraph` geoms for drawing edges, including `geom_conn_bundle` and `geom_edge_diagonal`, have a calculated index stat. It's a number from 0 to 1 of how far along the edge a point is. Note that the simplified versions of these geoms (`geom_*0`) don't calculate it. Some mentions of it are in [this blog post](https://www.data-imaginist.com/2017/ggraph-introduction-edges/) by the `ggraph` author.

In this case, map the index `stat(index)` to color inside your bundle's `aes`, then set a gradient scale with (`scale_edge_color_gradient`, not `scale_color_gradient` as I initially tried).

In the example picture, I can't tell whether the width is also scaled, but the same would work, e.g. `edge_width = stat(index)`.

```r
library(ggraph)
library(igraph)

ggraph(tree, layout = "dendrogram", circular = TRUE) + 
  geom_edge_diagonal(alpha = 0.2) + 
  geom_conn_bundle(aes(color = stat(index)),
    data = get_con(from = 23, to = 42),
    alpha=0.8, 
    width=3,
    # colour="skyblue", 
    tension = 0.9
  ) +
  scale_edge_color_gradient(low = "green", high = "red")
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2019-03-09 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.1)</sup>

Comment: In addition to this, you can use `geom_conn_bundle2()` which interpolates between the scaled values at the end points. See the docs for more on this